# Displaying an explicit number of nested attributes in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms, formtastic, nested-attributes

Given three models:

1. Document
2. Asset
3. AssetCategory

A document accepts_nested_attributes_for assets (a document has_many assets), and an asset belongs_to an asset category.

**I would like to display a field for an asset attribute for each asset category.**

I am currently achieving this as follows. Controller:

```
def new
  @document = Document.new
  @asset_categories = AssetCategory.all
  @asset_categories.count.times { @document.assets.build }
end
```

View (this example uses the semantic_fields_for method provided by Formtastic, but this is just a thin wrapper around fields_for):

```
i=0
f.semantic_fields_for :assets do |asset_form|
  asset_form.input :attachment, :label => @asset_categories[i].name
  asset_form.input :asset_category, :as => :hidden, :value => @asset_categories[i].id
  i+=1
end
```

Is there a cleaner approach to this? I'm not so fond of the temporary variable i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller:

```
def new
  @document = Document.new
  AssetCategory.all.each do |ac|
    @document.assets.build :asset_category_id=>ac.id
  end
end
```

In the view:

```
f.semantic_fields_for :assets do |af|
  af.input :attachment, :label=>af.object.asset_category.name
  af.input :asset_category_id, :as => :hidden, :value => af.object.asset_category.id
end
```

Comment: I also needed "af.input :asset_category_id, :as => :hidden, :value => af.object.asset_category.id" in the view, or the asset category was not correctly set for the attachment when the form was submitted. This also meant that the document's assets were retained when render => :new was called from create if there were validation errors (i.e. they didn't need to be built a second time if no file was selected for a particular field).